# How to prove that $P(x_{0})$ is divisible by $(a+b)^3$

Tags: polynomials

I need a help for this question please.

> $P$ is a polynomial defined by
> $$P(x)=ab\left(a-c\right)x^{3}+\left(a^{3}-a^{2}c+2ab^{2}-b^{2}c+abc\right)x^{2}+\left(2a^{2}b+b^{2}c+a^{2}c+b^{3}-abc\right)x+ab\left(b+c\right)$$
> $$ a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}$$

1. I already proved  that $P(x)$ is divisible  by $$abx^{2}+\left(a^{2}+b^{2}\right)x+ab$$ and I found that
   $$P(x) = (abx^{2}+\left(a^{2}+b^{2}\right)x+ab)\left(\left(a-c\right)x+\left(b+c\right)\right)$$

**2. I need help for this question. I must prove then for $$x_{0}=\left(a+b+1\right)^{n}$$
$$ n \in \mathbb{N}$$
$$P(x_{0}) \text{ is divisible by }  (a+b)^3$$**

thanks

Comment: have you tried mod arithmetic ?

Comment: No, i Just try to factorise by (a+b)^3

Comment: Are you suppose to use certain ideas or are you free ? And/or do you want to use something specific ? 
I would personally use mod. Not sure if its the best though. But I think it will do fine.